# rewriting loops functions in numpy without using for or while

Tags: python, numpy, loops

I'm trying to reproduce the following functions using the numpy library, I want to produce an equivalent definition without using the keywords for or while. Im guessing you need to use broadcasting, newaxis, and reshape from numpy. but im new to numpy and doing loops without using "for" or "while" has been a mind-bender for me, especially while trying to work with nested loops.

```
def _bcast(x):
            x1, x2 = x
            y = np.empty(x1.shape)
            for i in range(x1.shape[0]):
                for j in range(x1.shape[1]):
                    for k in range(x1.shape[2]):
                        y[i,j,k] = (x1[i,j,k]+4)*(4*x2[j,k] - 4)
            return y
```

---

```
def _bcast_ax(x):
            x1, x2 = x
            y = np.empty((x1.shape[0], x2.shape[0], x2.shape[1]))
            for i in range(x1.shape[0]):
                for j in range(x2.shape[0]):
                    for k in range(x2.shape[1]):
                        y[i,j,k] = (4+x1[i,k])*(4*x2[j,k]-4)
            return y
```

---

```
def bcast(x):
  
    return (x1+4) * (4*x2 -4)
```

---

```
def bcast_ax(x):
   
    return (x**2)*(x[1]*2)*(x[2]**4)
```

I tried doing the following for these two functions, but they are not working.

just to clarify, i need this test to pass by both _bcast and bcast producing the same result. same for _bcast_ax and bcast_ax

```
def test_bcast(self):
        def _bcast(x):
            x1, x2 = x
            y = np.empty(x1.shape)
            for i in range(x1.shape[0]):
                for j in range(x1.shape[1]):
                    for k in range(x1.shape[2]):
                        y[i,j,k] = (x1[i,j,k]+4)*(4*x2[j,k] - 4)
            return y

        X = [(np.random.randn(3,4,5), np.random.randn(4,5)) for _ in range(3)]
        self._test_fun(ac.bcast, _bcast, X)
```

Comment: You need a [mcve], and also show the traceback for functions that "don't work".  By my reasoning, the first `_bast` shouldn't work because of a mismatch in indexing.

Comment: `X` is list of 3 tuples of arrays.  None of your functions work with that.  Give a proper [mcve] with correct indentation.

Answer (score 0):

Focusing on the

```
y[i,j,k] = (x1[i,j,k]+4)*(4*x2[j,k] - 4)
```

That means `y` and `x1` have same shape.  `x2` has the same last 2 dimensions.    We can reshape `x2` to have a new leading dimension `x2[None,...]`

```
y = (x1+4)*(4*x2[None,...] - 4)
```

but by the rules of broadcasting new leading dimensions are automatic

```
y = (x1+4)*(4*x2-4)
```

should work.

The key is to understand `broadcasting`.

### testing

```
In [169]: x1, x2 = np.arange(24).reshape(2,3,4), np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)
In [170]:             y = np.empty(x1.shape)
     ...:             for i in range(x1.shape[0]):
     ...:                 for j in range(x1.shape[1]):
     ...:                     for k in range(x1.shape[2]):
     ...:                         y[i,j,k] = (x1[i,j,k]+4)*(4*x2[j,k] - 4)
     ...: 
In [171]: y
Out[171]: 
array([[[ -16.,    0.,   24.,   56.],
        [  96.,  144.,  200.,  264.],
        [ 336.,  416.,  504.,  600.]],

       [[ -64.,    0.,   72.,  152.],
        [ 240.,  336.,  440.,  552.],
        [ 672.,  800.,  936., 1080.]]])
In [172]: (x1+4)*(4*x2-4)
Out[172]: 
array([[[ -16,    0,   24,   56],
        [  96,  144,  200,  264],
        [ 336,  416,  504,  600]],

       [[ -64,    0,   72,  152],
        [ 240,  336,  440,  552],
        [ 672,  800,  936, 1080]]])
```

Comment: im not sure i follow, should (x1+4)*(4*x2[None,...] - 4)  give me the answer?  Im getting the following error return  (x1+4)*(4*x2[None,...] - 4)
TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "int") to tuple

Comment: I removed the 'oops' block.  `x1,x2=x` is unpacking a tuple, so the original analysis still is valid.